# using context resource in gwt 2 hosted mode

Tags: java, gwt

I am moving a web app from gwt 1.5 to gwt 2.0. I am trying to connect to the a database resource I have in my context.xml file.In gwt 1.5 I had set up root.xml in tomcat->conf->gwt->localhost. I have no idea where to set  up the resource in GWT 2.0. I tried placing my context.xml file in war->META-INF with no luck.

Anyone have an idea where to place the context.xml file to be able to use a jndi database resource in GWT 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trick was to use jetty-web.xml in WEB-INF